# PHP Index error in switch instruction

Tags: php

this is a beginner code structure question:

to solve this problem i want to try to just make two documents (a html and a php) to clean it up.

This piece of code should should take a price, number, percent of tax and a number for sales while the case statements Value is chosen in the FORM. Instead after i chose numbers for the FORM i get a few error messages about indexes. The indexes are set through my input into the form so i don't know what i have to change so the code is running correctly.

The else should kick in if the sum is lower than 90. How do i have to order the Code so it does work like intended? I oriented on a tutorial.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Circe</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Circe: Eingabeformular</h4>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"method="get">
  Artikelpreis
  <input type="text" name="warenpreis" size="10"> € <br />
  Stückzahl
  <input type="text" name="anzahl" size="10"> Stck <br />
  Mehrwehrsteuer
  <select name="msteuer" size="2">
    <option value="7" >7%</option>
    <option value="19" >19%</option>
  </select> <br />
  <select name="umsatz" size="10">
    <option value="1000" >1000</option>
    <option value="2000" >2000</option>
    <option value="3000" >3000</option>
    <option value="5000" >5000</option>
    <option value="0" >0</option>
  </select> <br />
  <input type="submit" name="gesendet" value="Berechnen"> <br />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_GET['gesendet'])){
            // Variablen deklararien und Werte zuweisen.
            $artikel = $_POST['warenpreis'];
            $anzahl = $_POST['anzahl'];
            $msteuer = $_POST['msteuer']/100;
        $umsatzgrenze = $_POST['umsatz'];
        $umsatzrabbat = 0;
            $summe = 0;
        $nettosumme = 0;
        $mwsteuerpreis = 0;
            $vkosten = 5.95;
        $rabbat = 0;
        $prozent = 0;
        $lieferkostenpreis = 0;

        switch($umsatzgrenze){
            case "1000":
                $umsatzrabbat = 0.02;
                break;
            case "2000":
                $umsatzrabbat = 0.03;
                break;
            case "3000":
                $umsatzrabbat = 0.03;
                break;
            case "5000":
                $umsatzrabbat = 0.05;
                break;
            case "0":
                $umsatzrabbat = 0;
                break;
            default:
                echo "Sie haben keinen Umsatz ausgewählt!<br>";
        }
         $nettosumme = ($artikel * $anzahl);
         $rabatt = ($nettosumme * $umsatzrabatt);
         $mwsteuerpreis = ($nettosumme - $rabatt) * $msteuer;
         $summe = $nettosumme + $mwsteuerpreis;
         $prozent = $umsatzrabbat * 100;

         if ($summe < 99) {
            $lieferkostenpreis = $summe + $vkosten;
            echo "Sie bekommen: " . $prozent . " %<br>";
            echo "Die Gesamtkosten betragen: " . $lieferkostenpreis . " €<br>";
            echo "Die Lieferpauschale beträgt unter einem Bestellwert von 99€: " . $vkosten . " €<br>";
            echo "Die Artikel kosten netto: " . $nettosumme . " €<br>";
            echo "Die Mehrwertsteuersumme beträgt: " . $mwsteuerpreis . " €<br>";
       }
       else {

           echo "Sie bekommen: " . $prozent . " %<br>";
           echo "Die Gesamtkosten betragen: " . $lieferkostenpreis . " €<br>";
           echo "Die Lieferpauschale beträgt unter einem Bestellwert von 99€: " . $vkosten . " €<br>";
           echo "Die Artikel kosten netto: " . $nettosumme . " €<br>";
           echo "Die Mehrwertsteuersumme beträgt: " . $mwsteuerpreis . " €<br>";
         }

      }

        ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: your form method is get but your accessing value by post method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you need to access values in php through `post` method:
   Change the **`if(isset($_GET['gesendet']))`** to **`if(isset($_POST['gesendet']))`**
2. If you need to access values in php through `get`method:
   Change the :

   ```
   $artikel = $_POST['warenpreis'];
   $anzahl = $_POST['anzahl'];
   $msteuer = $_POST['msteuer']/100;
   $umsatzgrenze = $_POST['umsatz'];
   ```

   To:

   ```
   $artikel = $_GET['warenpreis'];
   $anzahl = $_GET['anzahl'];
   $msteuer = $_GET['msteuer']/100;
   $umsatzgrenze = $_GET['umsatz'];
   ```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: thanks. Now i have no error messages anymore but the script does not echo anything at all anymore, too.

Comment: does the GET Method not work for a one page document? or do i have to do further steps

Comment: it definitely works. Just follow the first step i suggested.

Comment: maybe a server issue here. i try it again

Comment: found it.. forget to set the form action to post.

Answer (score 2):

I can't know what's the errore you get bit I immagine that PHP is saying "Sie haben keinen Umsatzausgewählt!".
If I'm right, you're noto checking correctly the values in the `switch` statement. If you want to solve this, you just need to use the `var_dump` function on `$umsatzgrenze` variable and check its type. In case of INT, remove the quotes around the number in the switch.
 If this still get problems, try with a `print_r` function on your `$_POST` array to check if all the variables you need are set properly.
I hope this is what you we're looking for!

Comment: @flightofthepenguin Can you please rate positively my answer and set it as your answer? I'm trying ti grow up on StackOverflow, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1)  your form method is `get method` but your accessing value by `post method` so its kick you with `undefined index` error

```
  $artikel = $_GET['warenpreis'];
  $anzahl = $_GET['anzahl'];
  $msteuer = $_GET['msteuer']/100;
  $umsatzgrenze = $_GET['umsatz'];
```

2)  `$rabatt = ($nettosumme * $umsatzrabatt);` in this line there no variable like `$umsatzrabatt` i think it's typo . it should be `$umsatzrabbat`

3) First of all check all the field is not empty and then do the calculation .